# Creating a simple django form

Tags: python, django, forms, django-forms

I am new to django and and I'm trying to use forms.I want to create a form with two `CharFields`. Here is where I am so far -

`forms.py`

```
from django import forms
class NameForm(forms.Form):
key = forms.CharField(label='Enter Key:', max_length=2)
value = forms.CharField(label='Enter Value:', max_length=4)
```

`template.html`

```
<form action="/new-page/" method="GET">
{{ form }}
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

What I want is to take the data in this form and simply use that data in my function `myfunc`

`views.py`

```
def myfunc(request,id):
  key = request.GET.get('key') 
  value = request.GET.get('value')
```

where id is the id of the page where the form appears like so `url/places/1/`
I want the `action` to send the id and the key,value pair to the function to use on submit.Validation is not required. Can someone help me understand the concept here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your views.py should look like:

```
def myfunc(request, id):
    form = NameForm(request.GET or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        key = form.cleaned_data['key']
        value = form.cleaned_data['value']
        # do something with key and value
```

Comment: What about the  `action` ?

Comment: `action` in the form is the url that points to function `myfunc`. You also need to add `{% csrf_token %}` inside your form. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/csrf/#how-to-use-it

Comment: That is what I'm asking. Right now the action just points to a random url. How do I make it point to the url generated by the view `myfunc`. Also, the `{{ form }}` tag in my template doesn't render anything. Is there a way to pass the form in `forms.py` as a context so that the `{{ form }}` tag renders it?

Comment: You should look at this on how to render form:https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/#form-rendering-options. Your views.py function should always have corresponding url. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/intro/tutorial03/#writing-more-views